# How to fix Sometimes happen 500 error in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have done configurations to fetch data from database and assign corresponding to it.
It works Fine. but sometimes issues happen like undefined index or target class not found.if i refresh again issues not happen that time.

Note: sometimes happens only. so i can't find what exact issue.

AppserviceProvider in boot method i call below function

```
public function CustomInit(){
    if (env('DB_DATABASE') != '') {
        // Configuration Setup for Email Settings
        if (Schema::hasTable('email_settings')) {
            $result = DB::table('email_settings')->get();

            $mail_config = array(
                "default" => $result[0]->value,
                "from" => [
                    "address" => $result[3]->value,
                    "name" => $result[4]->value
                ],
                "mailers" => [
                    "smtp" => [
                        'transport' => 'smtp',
                        "host" => $result[1]->value,
                        "port" => $result[2]->value,
                        "encryption" => $result[5]->value,
                        "username" => $result[6]->value,
                        "password" => $result[7]->value,
                        'timeout' => null,
                    ],
                ]
            );

            Config::set('mail',$mail_config);

            $site_settings = SiteSettings::all();

            Config::set(
                [
                'laravel-backup.backup.name' => $site_settings[0]->value,
                'laravel-backup.monitorBackups.name' => $site_settings[0]->value,
                'laravel-backup.notifications.mail.from' => $result[3]->value,
                'laravel-backup.notifications.mail.to' => $result[3]->value,
                ]
            );
        }

        if (Schema::hasTable('site_settings')) {
            $site_settings = DB::table('site_settings')->get()->pluck('value', 'name');
            $rand = str_random(6);
            if ($site_settings['site_url'] == '' && $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
                $url = "http://" . @$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
                $url .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), "", @$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
                SiteSettings::where('name', 'site_url')->update(['value' =>$url]);
            }
            if (!@$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
                Config::set('app.url', $site_settings['site_url']);
                URL::forceRootURL($site_settings['site_url']);
            }

            View::share("site_name", $site_settings['site_name']);
            View::share("version", $site_settings['version']);
            View::share("version", str_random(4));
            View::share('favicon', url('logos/' . $site_settings['favicon'] . '?v=' . $rand));
            View::share('logo_web_1', url('logos/' . $site_settings['logo_web_1'] . '?v=' . $rand));
            View::share('logo_web_2', url('logos/' . $site_settings['logo_web_2'] . '?v=' . $rand));
            View::share('email_logo', url('logos/' . $site_settings['email_logo'] . '?v=' . $rand));
            View::share('web_favicon', url('logos/' . $site_settings['favicon'] . '?v=' . $rand));

            define('SITE_NAME', $site_settings['site_name']);
            define('LOGO_URL', url('logos/' . $site_settings['logo_web_1'] . '?v=' . $rand));
            define('EMAIL_LOGO', url('logos/' . $site_settings['email_logo'] . '?v=' . $rand));
            define('FAV_ICON', url('logos/' . $site_settings['favicon'] . '?v=' . $rand));
        }

        if (Schema::hasTable('join_us')) {
            $join_us = DB::table('join_us')->get()->pluck('value', 'name');

            View::share("app_store", $join_us['app_store']);
            View::share("play_store", $join_us['play_store']);

        }
        if (Schema::hasTable('api_credentials')) {
            // For Google Key
            $google_map_result = DB::table('api_credentials')->where('site', 'GoogleMap')->get();
            define('MAP_KEY', $google_map_result[0]->value);
            define('MAP_SERVER_KEY', $google_map_result[1]->value);
            View::share('map_key', $google_map_result[0]->value);

            // For TWILLO Key
            $twillo_result = DB::table('api_credentials')->where('site', 'Twillo')->get();
            define('TWILLO_SID', $twillo_result[0]->value);
            define('TWILLO_TOKEN', $twillo_result[1]->value);
            define('TWILLO_FROM', $twillo_result[2]->value);
            // For TWILLO Key

            $fcm_result = DB::table('api_credentials')->where('site', 'FCM')->get();

            Config::set(
                ['fcm.http' => [
                'server_key' => $fcm_result[0]->value,
                'sender_id' => $fcm_result[1]->value,
                'server_send_url' => 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
                'server_group_url' => 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification',
                'timeout' => 10,
                ],
                ]
            );

        }

        $current_route = url()->current();

        if (Route::current()) {
            $current_route = Route::current()->uri();
        }
        View::share('current_route', $current_route);
    }


}
```

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is don't try and read the .env file in your controller, retrieve the values through a corresponding config file instead.

Long answer - since Laravel 5.2.0 "if you use the config:cache command during deployment you MUST make sure you are only calling the env function from within your configuration files, and not from anywhere else in your application" - https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0

In the code you've cited you're calling the .env file direct with :

```
if (env('DB_DATABASE') != '') {
```

Depending on which driver you're using, instead you want to retrieve this through the config/database.php file :

```
if(config('database.mysql.database' != '') {
```

That will provide a more stable method of retrieving the relevant value so you can see if it is empty or not.